# Sorting Function Change through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

i am working on an external page where i have no control. they have their own logic written for sorting and i cannot edit it. I have seen the sorting functionality and it is not jquery based, it all happens with code being send from url and sort it...

now they have written like javascript:sort(1); for all the columns they have in creasing order like javascript:sort(2); and columns do vary

Now i am trying to do one such step ahead where i want to replace the occurrence of javascript:sort(dynamic id's going);, with my own function but it should use the dynamic id;s as it:

like for javascript:sort(1); - it will write it as javascript:sortingmyway(1); like this

i will add my own logic there then

i am tring like this:

```
$("#container").find('a').replace('href=javascript:sort(*)','href=javascript:mysortinmg(*)')>
```

like i should use * to keep their numbers and use them in my sorting as it:

is this possible

Answer (score 0):

You can use `attr` method with `String.prototype.replace`:

```
$("#container").find('a').attr('href', function(i, old) {
    var col = old.match(/javascript:\s*sort\((.*?)\)/)[1];
    return 'javascript:mysortinmg(' + col + ')';
});
```

It will turn

```
href="javascript:sort(2)" -> href="javascript:mysortinmg(2)"
href="javascript:sort(12, 32)" -> href="javascript:mysortinmg(12, 32)"
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7dwpj2jc/

Comment: giving me an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

Comment: Can you post HTML this code is failing on? I need to adjust regular expression.

Comment: TypeError: old.match(...) is null

Comment: I know. Because your HTML is not the same as you posted in question. Post failing example.

Comment: %2Fjavascript%3Asort(1)%3B -  inconsole i see the link as

Comment: Strange that href is URL encoded. Try this then: `var col = decodeURIComponent(old).match(/javascript:\s*sort\((.*?)\)/)[1];`. Should work in this case.

Comment: it is like this: <a href="javascript:sort(1);">

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66867/discussion-between-acf-jjjq-and-dfsq).

Comment: seems i am stuck now, what i think is: it will be better to replace jquery:sort to the actual url, i am trying like this but getting an error: `var hrefcall = e.currentTarget.toString(); var col = decodeURIComponent(old).match(/javascript:\s*sort\((.*?)\)/)[1];
         return hrefcall+'&sortBy='+'('+col+')';`

Comment: Why can't you just use the script I postes. It works in demo, check it and compare with your situation to find out why it fails for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can just define your own sort() function. The browser will execute the most closely scoped or the most recently defined function if they are both scoped the same.

In other words, just add your sort() function to your page, and it will override the execution of their sort.